# How to load a JSON file in python 2.7

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am not able to load the following 'data.json' file in python 2.7.11,

file data.json

```
{
  "name":xyz,
  "age":12
}
```

The code i am using the load the above file,

```
import json
json_data = open ('data.json').read ()
json.loads(json_data)
```

I always get the following error

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

In the meantime,i also tried using yaml.load and it worked fine. But i wanted to know what is that i am doing wrong.

Comment: Try with `json.load()` and pass the file directly. My glass ball suggests: encoding issue.

Comment: even that throws the same exception @dhke

Comment: Ah. I must have been blind. `"name": xyz` isn't valid JSON. `xyz` isn't a literal. Did you mean `"name": "xyz"`?

Comment: yes, you are right! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is invalid.

Remember, if you're using alphabetical characters in a json Value, it's a string. So you have to write it within double quotes, like so:

```
{
  "name":"xyz",

  "age":12

}
```

Hopefully, this fix should solve your problem.